# Two layouts for same same activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code in my activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isPreviouslyLoggedIn()) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final TextView revolution=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final Button login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        final Button signUp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);

        login.setOnClickListener(loginListener);
        signUp.setOnClickListener(signUpListener);

    }

    else {
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PickUpActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

When the `if` statements are executed, the `layout` is set to splash. However, in cases when the `else` statement is executed the layout is not set to `home` and the `intent` is directly started. Why is this happening and how can I prevent this?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? The code does exactly what you said to him :) . Sets the home but then instantly starts the PickUpActivity. When do you want to start that activity?

Comment: Does the PickUpActivity setContentView? What can be happening is that, home layout is set, you start a new Activity that sets another layout

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in the else block?

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar Basically, I just want to call another activity but the intent takes a couple of seconds.  I want a layout to show a image(or anything other than a black screen) for that couple of seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way..

```
protected boolean active = true;
    protected int time = 5000;

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while (active && (waited < time)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if (active) {
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                } finally {
                    finish();
                    Intent Go_Activity = new Intent(Screen.this, otherActivity.class);
                    startActivity(Go_Activity);
                    stop();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
```

It help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set Any Time or Thread to wait some time to go next activity. When else statement executed then layout set but for few time. for this reason you do not able to show it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You know what are you trying to ask ?? After setting content view straightly you are starting the another activity so it will show the new(started)activity layout... what is wrong then ?

Comment: the thing is that the intent takes a while to start the activity due to which there is a black screen for a couple of seconds. I want a layout to show a image(or anything other than a black screen) for that couple of seconds.

Comment: try to start the activity in a different thread then hopes your issue will be fixed then ..